# Linking a database table cell to a TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm looking for a way to link a database table to a textbox in my WPF application. I need to take a specific cell from the table and display it in a read only text box. I've not been able to find a solution personally, and the internet has held no favor either. Thanks for the help in advance!

Post any questions in the comments, I'll edit this question and make it more specific.

Comment: This question is very broad because this is a multi-step process with many possible ways to do it.  Do you need to know how to load data from a database?  Or have you done that, and you need to know to display it in WPF?  Is it the XAML part you need help with, or the data binding part?

Comment: I have the tables, I just need to pull from the specific cells in said tables. I need help data binding said cells into a specific controller, such as a textbox.

Comment: C# can't go from table cells to a text box.  You use ADO.NET or the Entity Framework or something like that to read from a database into memory.  Once you have it in memory you can data bind it to the UI just like any other variable.

Comment: Thanks @MobyDisk, that helped a lot and I was able to complete that portion of my project. Thank you again!